# Create/Loop through different folders and Saving files

Tags: python, operating-system, os.path

I want to write a code that goes to the input_folder[i], check if output_folder[i] exists, if not then creates output_folder[i]. After defininng input and output_folder_1, it goes to the files in the input, performs an operation on it, and saves it output_folder_1.

```
Inputs = [dir for dir in os.listdir() if dir.startswith("DATASET_")]
for i in Inputs:
     input_dir = i
     try:
          output_dir = [dir for dir in os.listdir() if dir.startswith("Result_"+ i)]
     except:
          print(f'Output_Dir  {output_dir} does not exist. Creating new')
          output_dir = os.mkdir("Result_" + i )
          function(input_dir, output_dir)
```

It creates input and output directories but when the function code doesn't execute. If I call the function outside of except statement, it gives an error. The next part of code is as follow:

```
def function(input_dir, output_dir):
     os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)
     im_list = [file for file in os.listdir(input_dir) if file.endswith(".png")]
```

The error is as follow:

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Comment: You could have done this by using `os.walk` which could be easier in this case. BTW what is `function(input_dir, output_dir)`? Shouldn't you call the function as `overlay_labels_and_save(input_dir, output_dir)`

Comment: Your `if` conditions could be handled by `"*.png"` glob patterns: https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html . (os.walk is nice too, but glob's more convenient here.)

Comment: The error I am getting is because the function is expecting a str, byte or os.PathLike object but its getting a list but I am calling the function in the same loop for input_dir(i) and output_dir(i).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function's 2nd arg is misnamed, it should be `output_dirs` (plural).

And then it would be clear that within the function you'd want to
be iterating over it.

Alternatively, the function signature is perfect already,
and the caller should be iterating over a list of dirs,
supplying a single directory to the function each time.

Comment: so, I should store the list of directories in input_dir and output_dir and then iterate in the 'function(input_dir, output_dir)' ?

Comment: I was explaining that `output_dir = [dir for dir in ...]` is Just Wrong, it's using the wrong name for the identifier, which impairs how we reason about the code. The singular `dir` is fine. But you should be assigning to a plural `output_dirs`, since it is a collection of potentially many directories. We want to either get the singular / plural distinction correct up in the caller, or get it correct down in the called function. It's the mismatch between the two that is causing you grief.